# How many Notification URLs does eBay accept?

Tags: paypal, notifications, ebay-api

I don't know much about eBay API, and their documentation is not good as they are not full information at all.

Paypal Notifications only accept 1 URL. I wonder how many Notification URLs eBay accept?

And how they send Notifications to your webserver? They will send a HTTP Request to your web server URL like Paypal, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually think they have [plenty of great documentation about it](https://www.x.com/developers/ebay/products/platform-notifications-api).  The eBay Platform Notifications systems works over the API so you can setup different listeners for different notifications.  That link has all the information you would need to get going.